# Demonstrate that $\displaystyle \frac{(2n - 2)!!}{(2n - 3)!!} \simeq 1.7 \sqrt{n}$

Tags: approximation, factorial

As in the title, I know that

$\displaystyle \frac{(2n - 2)!!}{(2n - 3)!!} = \frac{(2n - 2)(2n - 4)\cdots 4 \cdot 2}{(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \cdots 3 \cdot 1} \simeq 1.7 \sqrt{n}$

Could you give some hint to prove it?

(should I look the series expansion of $\sqrt{n}$?)

Thank you anyway!

Comment: Question: what you mean with $\simeq$?

Comment: "Almost equal", that is: the left side is not exactly the right one, but it is very close to it. Maybe you use $\approx$ instead of $\simeq$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Stirling formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$\frac{(2n - 2)(2n - 4)\cdots 4 \cdot 2}{(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \cdots 3 \cdot 1}
=\frac{(2n - 2)^2(2n - 4)^2\cdots 4^2 \cdot 2^2}
{(2n - 2)!}
\\=
2^{2n-2}
\frac{(n - 1)^2(n - 2)^2\cdots 2^2 \cdot 1^2}
{(2n - 2)!}
\\=2^{2n-2}
\frac{((n - 1)!)^2}{(2n - 2)!}
\sim 2^{2n-2}\frac{(n-1)^{2n-2}e^{-2n+2}2\pi n}
{(2n - 2)^{2n-2}e^{-2n+2}\sqrt{2\pi 2n}}=
{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$

Comment: You obtain the right result, but why do you consider $2 \pi n$ instead of $2 \pi (n - 1)$ in both numerator and denominator?

Comment: it doesn't change the limit of the ratio!

Comment: Ok, so you are strictly talking about the limit for $n \to \infty$ (and I agree). But for smaller and finite values of $n$ this could change the result and the approximation, isn't it?

Comment: This approximation is only valid when $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Take the square root of the Wallis product...

Answer (score 2):

Also with Stirling's approximations, the comparison of numerical results :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just extending what mookid gave, you can have an extremely good approximation using
$$ \frac{(2n - 2)!!}{(2n - 3)!!} \simeq \sqrt{\pi n } \left(1-\frac{3}{8 n}-\frac{7}{128 n^2}\right)$$